# Application Not Working Fine After 7 Minutes?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-leaks, crash

I am working on iPhone application.This application works fine first 6 or 7 minute but after that some of the function of my application not works. For example I am using Clock sound effect in my application using NSTimer it works for 6 or 7 minutes after that it automatically Silent and Second EXp this code,

```
   -(IBAction)retryagain
   {    
    PlistDemoViewController *sec=[[PlistDemoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlistDemoViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:sec animated:YES];
    [sec release];
    }
```

This Code works fine Before 6 or 7 minutes.but after that it crash and my console look like This.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/moon/Library/Application
Support/iPhone Simulator/4.1/Applications/B4AA89F7-E4C8-47D1-B50E-291236543EBF
/PlistDemo.app> (loaded)' with name 'PlistDemoViewController''


              *** Call stack at first throw:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x029cbb99 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x027c040e objc_exception_throw + 47
2   CoreFoundation                      0x02984238 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
3   CoreFoundation                      0x029841aa +[NSException raise:format:] + 58
4   UIKit                               0x004c84f8 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 2024
5   UIKit                               0x004c9eb5 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 168
6   UIKit                               0x0037f95f -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 70
7   UIKit                               0x0037d675 -[UIViewController loadView] + 120
8   UIKit                               0x0037d54f -[UIViewController view] + 56
9   UIKit                               0x0037ede3 -[UIViewController viewControllerForRotation] + 36
10  UIKit                               0x0037b026 -[UIViewController _visibleView] + 90
11  UIKit                               0x006411d2 -[UIClientRotationContext initWithClient:toOrientation:duration:andWindow:] + 269
12  UIKit                               0x002f9d17 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:duration:force:] + 921
13  UIKit                               0x0056c67b -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:] + 768
14  UIKit                               0x0038110d -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:withTransition:] + 2937
15  PlistDemo                           0x00002cd3 -[PlistDemoViewController retryagain] + 115
16  UIKit                               0x002d37f8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
17  UIKit                               0x0035ede0 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
18  UIKit                               0x00361262 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
19  UIKit                               0x0035fe0f -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
20  UIKit                               0x002f73d0 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
21  UIKit                               0x002d8cb4 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
22  UIKit                               0x002dd9bf _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7672
23  GraphicsServices                    0x03516822 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
24  CoreFoundation                      0x029acff4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
25  CoreFoundation                      0x0290d807 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
26  CoreFoundation                      0x0290aa93 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
27  CoreFoundation                      0x0290a350 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
28  CoreFoundation                      0x0290a271 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
29  GraphicsServices                    0x0351500c GSEventRunModal + 217
30  GraphicsServices                    0x035150d1 GSEventRun + 115
31  UIKit                               0x002e1af2 UIApplicationMain + 1160
32  PlistDemo                           0x00002a5e main + 84
33  PlistDemo                           0x00002a01 start + 53
34  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
    )

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
Data Formatters unavailable (Error calling dlopen for: "/Developer/Applications    /Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/GDBMIDebugging.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/PBGDBIntrospectionSupport.A.dylib": "dlopen(/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/GDBMIDebugging.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/PBGDBIntrospectionSupport.A.dylib, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/GDBMIDebugging.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/PBGDBIntrospectionSupport.A.dylib: open() failed with errno=24")
 (gdb)
```

Anyone can guide me about this issue?

Comment: Can you check the code of 
-[PlistDemoViewController retryagain] at 115th line or around that?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT 2:

would you try using this code?

```
PlistDemoViewController *sec= [[PlistDemoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:sec animated:YES];
```

since your nib is named after your controller, is should do the same; I only hope, without crashing...

EDIT:

If you read carefully the error message:

> 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'PlistDemoViewController

it says that the PlistDemoViewController cannot be found.

Can you check that the name is spelled correctly?

OLD ANSWER:

You are presenting a modal view in `PlistDemoViewController` `retryagain` method and it fails. My suggestion is for you to 
check all the arguments you are passing in and also double check the definition of the xib your are trying to display.

Comment: Thanx @sergio i check all these thing Clearly i think it may be due to some Memory leaks.R My Console show any memory leaks.?

Comment: From the console log, there is no way to say if there are memory leaks. You could run the app under instruments to check that, but if the problem was due to scarce memory, then you would see a few memory warnings in the console just prior to the crash...

Comment: one more thing: are you sure that the `retryagain` method is executed more than once? could you put some NSLog trace in there?

Comment: thanx for helping me so for.but its not issue with retryagain method.my Clock backgroundsound also get silent after 6 minutes which show that after 6 minute some thing happens in my application.which crash all these methods.

Answer (score 0):

What is the time interval that you are using to schedule the timer.

Actually presenting a view controller animatedly takes some time.

Please add 5 more seconds to your time interval or present you view controller without animation. I think that can help you.